# I need to make 2 different AVG colums, but can't seem to get this to work

Tags: sql, average

```
SELECT AVG(goals1) FROM matches
WHERE cid='1'
(SELECT AVG(goals2) FROM matches
WHERE cid='2')
;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT AVG(goals1) AvgCid1, (SELECT AVG(goals2) FROM matches WHERE cid='2') AvgCid2
FROM matches
WHERE cid='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `UNION` between the statements like this:

```
SELECT AVG(goals1) FROM matches
WHERE cid='1'
UNION
SELECT AVG(goals2) FROM matches
WHERE cid='2'
```

You may need to name the columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT AVG(goals1) AS goals1 FROM matches WHERE cid='1') t1
full outer join
(SELECT AVG(goals2) AS goals2 FROM matches WHERE cid='2') t2
ON t1.goals1 <> t2.goals2;
```